# uitableview separator missing on last cell when table footer is specified

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

When I specify a table footer (not a section footer) for my UITableView, the separator line below the last cell is not being drawn. Note that it is drawn if the footer is empty:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

but not if the tableFooterView contains anything else.

Any ideas as to how to get the separator line for the last cell to be drawn?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set the footer then as it’s being reset when another view object get drawn.

Comment: I am setting the footer to something other than an empty UIView().  The footer draws correctly, but the separator line after the last cell is not.

Comment: Sounds like you’re overriding it as opposed to explicitly setting it

Comment: In the case where the last separator disappears, I am creating the footer in Xcode Interface Builder.  The footer itself is displayed correctly. The only problem is the missing last cell's separator.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?